# Windows 8 RT Internet Explorer- SVG plugin?

Tags: windows-8, tablet, svg, gis

My current company is using a GIS firm that requires us to web-interface with it specifically with 'Internet Explorer' and with the 'current' 6/7 year old Adobe SVG Plugin.
I've thrown every user-agent changing browser on Android, Playbook, iPad at it- at *best* it'll log me in and just offer me to download the svg file, instead of displaying/interacting-with it in the browser.
A Windows 8 Pro tablet (ala ElitePad with 3G) is the last resort, but RT is far cheaper.  Can RT IE play-ball with SVG sites?

Comment: Are you using the desktop mode IE or Metro IE? The latter doesn't support external plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of. I have tried many ways to get these sites to work on RT surface 2 and no luck. If it does work on surface 2 pro please let us know. It looks like I will now have to buy a new Surface 2 Pro. The down side is it cost around 900 and does not come with office like the RT version. So you have to spend another 150-200 on office to have a real replacement for a company issue laptop.